# Ubuntu freezes when I plug in external hard drive formatted as exFAT

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb

What can be hanging up my system.

I thought I went through the necessary steps to enable mounting of an exFAT-formatted hard drive:

```
# Install fuse-exfat and exfat-utils
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install fuse-exfat
sudo apt-get install exfat-utils

# Restart Ubuntu
sudo reboot
```

I can hear the hard drive spinning before I attach the device to Ubuntu (via parallels).  The moment I 'plug into Ubuntu' the hard drive whirrs down and stops spinning, the UI becomes unresponsive, and all of Ubuntu seems to hang.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue but not exactly the same.
I just deleted the **.Trash** hidden folder in my External Hard Disk and it solved the issue.